# Writing a script for Python 3: A children song

Tags: python

So, I need to write this children song with functions and not just repeated print codes for each line. The lyrics are below, and I also included what I have so far. What do I do next?

> There was an old lady who swallowed a fly.
>   I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
>   Perhaps she'll die.
>
> There was an old lady who swallowed a spider,
>   That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
>   She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
>   I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
>   Perhaps she'll die.
>
> There was an old lady who swallowed a bird.
>   How absurd to swallow a bird.
>   She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
>   That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
>   She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
>   I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
>   Perhaps she'll die.
>
> There was an old lady who swallowed a cat.
>   Imagine that to swallow a cat.
>   She swallowed the cat to catch the bird.
>   She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
>   That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
>   She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
>   I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
>   Perhaps she'll die.
>
> There was an old lady who swallowed a dog.
>   My, what a hog, to swallow a dog.
>   She swallowed the dog to catch the cat.
>   She swallowed the cat to catch the bird.
>   She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
>   That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
>   She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
>   I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
>   Perhaps she'll die.
>
> There was an old lady who swallowed a horse.
>   She's dead, of course.

So far I have:

```
def main():
     title()  # print the title
     verse1() # fly verse
     verse2() # spider verse
     verse3() # bird verse      
     verse4() # cat verse      
     verse5() # dog verse
     lastverse() # horse verse

there was an old lady who swolled a %
# call main
main()
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, this is not readable.

Comment: *Remember, remember, the 5th closing vote, the one that will close your post. I know of know reason, why in this world of precision, someone would post what should be posted not.* You should make clear what your question is; posting a little poem and saying you'd like to implement verses is light years far from a reasonable question.

Comment: Poor approach, but great challenge. Don't know why it was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def title():
    text = """
     A children song
    """
    print(text)

def verse1():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a fly.
    I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
    Perhaps she'll die.
    """
    print(text)

def verse2():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a spider,
    That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
    She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
    I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
    Perhaps she'll die.
    """
    print(text)
def verse3():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a bird.
    How absurd to swallow a bird.
    She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
    That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
    She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
    I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
    Perhaps she'll die.
    """
    print(text)

def verse4():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a cat.
    Imagine that to swallow a cat.
    She swallowed the cat to catch the bird.
    She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
    That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
    She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
    I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
    Perhaps she'll die.
    """
    print(text)
def verse5():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a dog.
    My, what a hog, to swallow a dog.
    She swallowed the dog to catch the cat.
    She swallowed the cat to catch the bird.
    She swallowed the bird to catch the spider,
    That wriggled and jiggled and tickled inside her.
    She swallowed the spider to catch the fly.
    I don't know why she swallowed the fly.
    Perhaps she'll die.
    """
    print(text)

def lastverse():
    text = """
    There was an old lady who swallowed a horse.
    She's dead, of course.
    """
    print(text)

def main():
    title()  # print the title
    verse1()  # fly verse
    verse2()  # spider verse
    verse3()  # bird verse
    verse4()  # cat verse
    verse5()  # dog verse
    lastverse()  # horse verse

main()
```